# Camel and source/target system availabilites strategy

Tags: apache-camel, recovery, availability, service-not-available

I am new to Camel and am looking for patterns or strategies to manage the availability of a target system in a Camel route.

For example, say I want:
- to read input data from an file server
- process the data (data -> targetData)
- to send the target data (TargetData) to a target web site using Rest services (call it TargetSystem)

My question is what is the best strategy if the TargetSytem is down?

I understand that if a route fails it is possible to rollback the overall process. But in case TargetSystem is an external system and can be down for hours, I don't think trying to rollback the process untill the target system is up is a good approach.

Is there any pattern or strategy that fits well with this issue?

Regards

Gilles

Answer (score 0):

This is the pattern I use with a couple of systems.

- Persist your **TargetData** somewhere (Database table, JMS queue, Redis, ...)
- Create a route that reads unsent **TargetData** and sends it to **TargetSystem**

  - If transfer is OK, mark **TargetData** accordingly (eg: set a flag in the table row, remove from Queue, etc...)
- Trigger such route periodically from a timer and/or other routes. You can even trigger it with a shell command to manually "force" a resend of unsent data.

You can customize this to your needs and for example add logging where appropriate, keep track in a DB table when each tentative send occurs, how many times it failed, how many retries and so on...

You can now modularize your application in 2 modules: one that receives **Data** and process it to **TargetData** and another that manages the transfer of **TargetData** to **TargetSystem**.
Module can mean 2 CamelContextes, 2 OSGi bundles, 2 totally separate Java applications.